# Underlying Connection Closed Unexpectedly after adding WSDL to Project

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have been given a WSDL file and I want to add a service to my application that sends data through the service.

I added the WSDL File by going:

1. Right Click on Project -> Add Service Reference
2. Click Advanced -> Add Web Reference
3. Added the WSDL File URL to the URL textbox
4. Add Reference

The Reference Appears under the Web Reference folder.

I added this code:

```
        using (var client = new getSubmitClaimWSD())
        {
            SubmitClaimRequest request = new SubmitClaimRequest()
            {
                buName = "Thermo King TSA",
                dealerNumber = "PHSDF",
                userName = "Roger",
                password = "1234",
                transactionType = "WARRANTY",
                claimLanguage = "ENG",
                serviceVersion = "1.0",
                claimType = "PARTS",
                failureDate = new DateTime(2014, 11, 26),
                faultFound = "PERFORM A FREE INSPECTION",
                inventorySerialNumber = "12352341",
                repairDate = new DateTime(2014, 11, 26),
                workOrderNumber = "testProcede1",
                conditionsFound = "test",
                workPerformed = "test",
                claimNotes = "test claim notes",
                faultLocation = "FF",
                failureDetail = "test",
                smrClaim = "N",
                forceToDraft = "Y",
                validateOnly = "N",
                commercialPolicy = "N",
                fuelSurcharge = 0,
                shopSupplies = 0,
                claimCurrency = "USD",
                workOrderSegment = "1",
                partsType = new[]
                {
                    new eachPart() {partNumber = "1234", partPrice = 100.78, partQuantity = 17, partType = "NONIR", partDescription = "test part desc"},
                    new eachPart() {partNumber = "5678", partPrice = 200.90, partQuantity = 1, partType = "IRREMOVED", partDescription = "test part desc 2"}
                }
            };

            var response = client.getSubmitClaim(null, request);
            var rsp = response.response;
            Console.WriteLine("Status {0}, claim {1}; {2} {3}, {4} errors", rsp.status, rsp.claimNumber,
                rsp.workOrderNumber, rsp.workOrderSegment, rsp.errorsType.Length);
        }
```

On this line:

```
var response = client.getSubmitClaim(null, request);
```

I keep getting the Exception:

[image]

This is the portion of my web.config

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <TKWarranty.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="TKWarranty_ThermalKing_getSubmitClaimWSD" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://data.thermoking.com:443/ws/ThermoKingWebServices.SubmitClaim:getSubmitClaimWSD</value>
      </setting>
    </TKWarranty.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

The WSDL file can be found [HERE](https://data.thermoking.com/ws/ThermoKingWebServices.SubmitClaim:getSubmitClaimWSD?WSDL)

When I have Fiddler running I get this error message on the same line:

[image]

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error? I have confirmed the port number in the web config.

Comment: Check if credentials are needed or if a proxy is blocking your way out.

Comment: What is best way of checking to see if a proxy is blocking me out?

Comment: I wasn't but then I tried it then I got 2 different error messages. I posted the error I get without fiddler as well as the error I get when using fiddler.

Comment: Usually you know when you are behind a proxy. The fastest way is to check your browser settings.

Comment: Also check if the firewall isn't blocking you or other network monitor like for example Forefront.

Comment: Nothing is blocking it. I do not have a username and password but from my understanding is that there is an error code response for an invalid username and password. So i think I should get a message back not matter what but that is not the case. I am working on getting the credentials now

Comment: Yes it is a error code for invalid username and password, but sometimes just close the connection, it happened to me last week with a network camera, why? I still  don't know.

Comment: Haha okay, well I will try that out once i get the username and password and see what happens.

Comment: In  `var response = client.getSubmitClaim(null, request);` line , the first argument according to VS Object Browser is a string testFlag. Are you sure that null is a correct value?

Comment: Ya, i noticed that as well and I have tried changing that to serveral different options ("true", "y", "yes", "test") and they all did the same thing. I emailed the company about that and what they were expecting but i believe that it does accept null values

Comment: @pepOS I got someone to respond to my email and he wants me to send him a copy of the xml that is generated by my code. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know. It's up to you.